# lwc LightningModal - hide x button

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

Is it possible to hide 'x' button

```
import { api } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
import { PREVIEW_MARKUP } from 'c/constants';

export default class EmailPreviewMainModal extends LightningModal {
    @api content;
    renderedCallback() {
        this.template.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = PREVIEW_MARKUP;
    }
    handleOkay() {
        this.close();
    }
} 



EmailPreviewMainModal.open({
                size: 'small',
                label: 'Custom one',
            });
```

Comment: There is no option to hide the X (close) button on the top right corner of the modal, as it is part of the standard UI.

You might need to build in the [custom component](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/).

Comment: i see but what is the option to do that? should i override <lightning-modal-header> ?

Comment: You need to remove the button above the header code.

Comment: Again, you'd have to write your own custom component, as you can't remove or hide the close button.

Comment: so seems like there is a need to folow the `old way` without new LightnigModal? Correct?

Comment: Unfortunately so.